# indent text up to the start of the first word of the previous line

Tags: indentation

When entering text I sometimes want the indented. Is there a way to avoid having to type blank characters up to the point where the first word on the previous line starts?

Comment: Have a look at the manual node on [indentation commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html).  I found this via a [google search for "emacs indent"](https://www.google.com/search?q=emacs+indent&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb).

Comment: should have thought about that, thanks. `M-x ident-relative` is the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Emacs manual entry on indentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html):

`M-x indent-relative`

Inserts whitespace at point, until point is aligned with the first non-whitespace character on the previous line (actually, the last non-blank line). If point is already farther right than that, runs tab-to-tab-stop instead—unless called with a numeric argument, in which case does nothing.

Comment: Please elaborate the answer.